# What will be the Java Regular expression to validate the subsequent pattern and get anything inside curly braces as a string? abc12={p,q}

Tags: java, regex

## What I need help with?

I want to write a Java Regular expression to validate the following expressions:

```
    fruits={apple,banana1,mango}

    fruits2={pear}

    x={}
```

All the above expressions should be considered valid. The general pattern is the following (but I am unable to write a regex as I am new to it):

```
someAlphaNumericString={empty,OneOrMoreCommaSeparated,Alpha123NumericStrings}
```

Some examples that should not be considered valid are:

```
        = {a,b}     // Missing string before =
    abc =           // Missing {} after =
    123 {1,3}       // Missing =   

 **Conclusion**: There should be an alphanumeric string before =
                 There should be a =
                 There should be at least {} after =
```

**Once the expression is valid**, I want to *get anything in between curly braces* { } *into a string*.

## What I have done so far?

So far, I have the following code:

```
 String tempStr = "a={b,c}";
 Pattern entry = Pattern.compile("\\{(.*?)\\}");  // This will match anything between {}
 Matcher matchPattern = entry.matcher(tempStr);

 String result;
 while(matchPattern.find()) {
    result = matchPattern.group(1);   // The result variable has "b,c"
 }
```

But this code lacks enough validation to meet all the aforementioned criteria.

Comment: please try this: `[\w]+=\{[\w,]*\}`

Comment: @enxaneta Thanks for the quick response, but I am getting "illegal escape character" error at the second character \w in your expression.

Comment: if input is  `{a,b}` return statement is what?  missing  `=` or  `alphanumeric string before =`

Comment: @drowny Statement should be checked to see if it is valid first. If valid, then only return the string in between curly braces; else any error message. If input is  {a,b}  then this statement is invalid and it is enough to give an error message.

Comment: I'm sorry about that Kusal K. I've tested it here: https://www.freeformatter.com/java-regex-tester.html#ad-output. It worked.

Comment: @enxaneta Thanks again.) It seems to work with [\\w]+=\\{[\\w,]*\\} (double backslash characters).